# Getting hours interval between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

Please can someone help me out here, i am trying to get a table of hours interval between a date range.

For example:

```
if starttime == 2012-02-06 23:59:00'
then endtime = '2012-02-29 10:26:17'
```

I should have a table(variable table) with content like this:

```
Start                    End                      Seconds
2012-02-06 23:59:00.000  2012-02-06 23:59:00.000  0
2012-02-29 09:00:00.000  2012-02-29 09:59:00.000  3540
2012-02-29 10:00:00.000  2012-02-29 10:26:17.000  1577
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - Hours column seems wrong to me. Should be zero in both cases.

Comment: Please check @LolCoder 's answer.

Comment: i have but  I want to break the date range into hour interval as well

Comment: His answer seems complete to me, so I'm probably missing something. Could you please show exactly what you want to accomplish? All the columns and values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the suggestions and comments.I finally got a was to solve may problem.

Below is the script to the solution i came up with:

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-02-06 23:59:01.000',20);
DECLARE @end_date datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-12-08 23:59:17.000',20);
DECLARE @org datetime  ;
DECLARE @end datetime  ;
DECLARE @datetable TABLE (h_start datetime, h_end datetime,h_sesc int);

WHILE (dateadd(second, -1, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @start_date)+1, 0))) < @end_date
BEGIN
SET @org = null;
SET @org = @start_date;
SET @end = (dateadd(second, -1, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @org)+1, 0)));
INSERT INTO @datetable (h_start, h_end,h_sesc)
VALUES(dateadd(second, 0,@org), @end,DATEDIFF(second, @org,@end));

SET @start_date = dateadd(second, 1,@end);

END;


INSERT INTO @datetable (h_start, h_end,h_sesc)
VALUES(dateadd(second, 0,@start_date), @end_date,DATEDIFF(second, dateadd(second, 0,@start_date),@end_date));

SELECT * FROM @datetable;
```

The above will give the folowing results:

```
h_start                 h_end                   h_sesc
2012-02-06 23:59:01.000 2012-02-06 23:59:59.000 58
2012-02-07 00:00:00.000 2012-02-07 00:59:59.000 3599
2012-02-07 01:00:00.000 2012-02-07 01:59:59.000 3599
2012-02-07 02:00:00.000 2012-02-07 02:59:59.000 3599
2012-02-07 03:00:00.000 2012-02-07 03:59:59.000 3599
2012-02-07 04:00:00.000 2012-02-07 04:59:59.000 3599
2012-02-07 05:00:00.000 2012-02-07 05:59:59.000 3599
```

..
..

```
2012-12-08 18:00:00.000 2012-12-08 18:59:59.000 3599
2012-12-08 19:00:00.000 2012-12-08 19:59:59.000 3599
2012-12-08 20:00:00.000 2012-12-08 20:59:59.000 3599
2012-12-08 21:00:00.000 2012-12-08 21:59:59.000 3599
2012-12-08 22:00:00.000 2012-12-08 22:59:59.000 3599
2012-12-08 23:00:00.000 2012-12-08 23:59:17.000 3557
```

Hope someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

With looking your expected table, you are getting differece in `second` between two time.

`SELECT  DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2012-02-29 09:00:00.000', '2012-02-29 09:59:00.000')` only gives 3540 which is difference of second.

To get the hour difference, you can try this code:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(hour, '2012-02-06 23:59:00.000', '2012-02-06 23:59:00.000')
```

Comment: i want the result to be broken down into hour intervals and the number of hours between the intervals

Comment: Please read the updated answer...You need to get first hour differece and then second difference which i have updated in my answer.

Comment: Did you have checked above answer?

Comment: it just give the seconds difference. I want to break the date range into hour interval as well

Comment: SELECT  DATEDIFF(hour, '2012-02-06 23:59:00.000', '2012-02-06 23:59:00.000') query simply gives hour difference but here in your data, there is only 59 minute differene which is considered as 0 hour....Change the hour part data and see the result with above query.

Comment: You are right. But you are using date range with one single hour. i want date range between multiple days to be broken down

Comment: Taking reference from above query, you can break down the multiple days date range.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-02-06 23:59:01.000', 20);
DECLARE @end_date datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-12-08 23:59:17.000', 20);

-- Using a recursive query after round down to full hours avoids a loop. The resulting intervals should be easier to use that way, e.g. you can but don't have to insert them into a table variable.
SET @start_date = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, @start_date), CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@start_date AS float)) AS datetime));
SET @end_date = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, @end_date), CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@end_date AS float)) AS datetime));
WITH RecursiveTimeIntervals AS
(SELECT @start_date Interval
UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, r.Interval)
FROM RecursiveTimeIntervals r
WHERE r.Interval < @end_date)
SELECT * 
FROM RecursiveTimeIntervals
ORDER BY 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DATEDIFF(hour, [start], [end])
```

See the [description on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp).